# Dictionary seems to not be populated

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to call a function in order to get a map back. Whenever I do this I get the following error;

```
[[:]]
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

The map gets populated via the following code;

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var activePlace = 0;
    var places = [Dictionary<String,String>()];
    //an array of maps, each map containing the data we need like long and lat

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if(places.count == 1){
            places.removeAtIndex(0);
        }
        places.append(["name":"Taj Mahal", "lat":"27.175282", "lon":"78.042209"]);
    }
```

And is called via this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tableView = TableViewController();
    var places = tableView.getArrayOfDetails();
    var index = tableView.getActivePlace();
    println(places);
```

Is it the order in which the viewDidLoad methods are executed which is causing this to be null?

Coincidently, if I change varActivePlace = 7; and then print that out from the viewDidLoad then it appears correctly so I don't know why the map would be empty?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`activePlace` is an instance property initialized at instantiation time, whereas `viewDidLoad` is called some time after the class is instantiated.

If both classes are instantiated, then it's not a surprise you are able to read the value set at initialization time:

```
var ActivePlace = 7;
```

Try initializing it to 0 and and then set a new value in `viewDidLoad` - or better, just set a breakpoint on each `viewDidLoad` to verify which gets called first.

What I think it happening is that the `viewDidLoad` method of the first class is executed *after* the `viewDidLoad` of the second class.